# Make infragistics' XamRichTextEditor visible to a screen reader

Tags: wpf, accessibility, infragistics, rich-text-editor, narrator

I have an accessibility problem with a rich text control in a clients' WPF project.
My client uses the `XamRichTextEditor` by infragistics, but Microsoft `Narrator` does not read its contents.
I have created a [small sample project](https://github.com/MikeLimaSierra/Examples/tree/main/StackOverflow/2021-03-XamRichTextEditor_Narrator) that has two buttons, a standard text box and the infragistics rich text editor.
The sample demonstrates that the screen reader works with all the elements correctly but fails to even recognize the editor.

Our goal is to make the editor control visible to the screen reader, but we are running out of ideas to do so.
We have logic in place that attaches the `AutomationProperties` to the control, and we manually fill them with content as well.

We have contacted infragistics about the matter, but there is not much to be expected in terms of screen reader support for the editor.

**Question:**
Is there any way to mark a control so that it is discovered by a screen reader?

**Note:**
I can't legally upload the infragistics libraries to GitHub, since it isn't freeware.
To get the sample to work you have to have infragistics WPF libraries already available on your system, and the existing references must be updated to your local paths. There are also [free trial downloads](https://www.infragistics.com/free-downloads) on the infragistics page, but that's a lot to download and install, so I don't particularly recommend doing so.

Comment: Seems like this feature does not supported by _Infragistics_. The [XamRichTextEditorAutomationPeer](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.editors.xamrichtexteditor~infragistics.automationpeers.xamrichtexteditorautomationpeer) exposes  `Infragistics.Controls.Editors.XamRichTextEditor` types to UI Automation, but no examples is provided with the _Infragistics_ SDK, how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, infragistic's support is zero, which is why I try to get there another way.

Comment: They just do not have time to develop the product and maintain its integrity. To support controls for a screen reader it is necessary to perform lot of tests.

Comment: Look at the following post - maybe you will find something useful:  [UI Automation Support](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/developers-guide-ui-automation-support)